# connect to psql and run SQL command from command line

Tags: postgresql, psql, command-line

I'm trying to write a quick line in bash that will use psql to connect to a database and delete all entries in two tables:

```
\connect some_db
DELETE from some_table
DELETE from another_table
```

I'd like to do this in one line of bash scripting like so:

```
psql -U <username> -c "\c some_db; DELETE from some_table; DELETE from another_table"
```

but it seems like I can't do that because the `\c` command creates a new context that the subsequent commands don't apply towards.

What's the right way to do this in a line or two from the CLI?

Comment: " psql .... <<EOF your command ... EOF  ".  You should read topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803651/how-to-execute-multiple-queries-using-psql-command-from-bash-shell  (your answer) and document: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the `\c` in the command specified with `-c`, you can specify the database as a parameter to `psql`:

```
psql -U <username> -d some_db -c "DELETE from some_table; DELETE from another_table"
```